# Fourier transformation lorentz peak

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, fourier-transform

I would like to calculate the Fourier Transformation of a Lorentz shaped peak. Removing all the physical constants, the integral boils down to:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(2 \pi x)}{(x - b)^2 + a}  dx$$

Under the assumption that $b = 0$ and using symmetry it may be transformed to:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_\infty^\infty \frac{\cos(2 \pi x)}{x^2 + a}  dx$$

After several steps I can evaluate it.
But I am completely lost in the case where $ b \neq 0$.
Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $u=x-b$?

Comment: Do you know that the Fourier Transform of a Lorentzian (also called Cauchy) is present in all tables of F.T. under the form $Kexp(-\pi L|\nu|)$ with $K$ and $L$ depending on the definition of the Fourier transform you take ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps sticking to the complex Fourier transform would work. The imaginary portion would contain information about phase which is what would account for an x -> x-b translation. Otherwise you're just extracting the relative level of all present frequencies, which doesn't differentiate between functions translated in space. Hence by solving for the b=0 case you're actually solving for them all so long as you don't care about phase.

Info on complex Fourier transform here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch31.pdf